# Select-Object join behavior in scripts

Tags: powershell, scripting, pipe

In [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/%23!topic/microsoft.public.windows.powershell/3SoPzDTkhVE) some is surprised that the following example doesn't work properly when run in a script

```
get-process | select-object cpu, name
dir | Select-Object name, length
```

> When I put this in a script the second command doesn't show the length

And the answer to this:

> PowerShell is joining both outputs. You could pipe the first output to
>   Format-Table [-auto] if you don't mind the format. Alternatively, you
>   can separate the first output from the following formatted output by
>   piping it to Out-Default, Out-Host, Out-string or Write-host

Now my question is why is it joining the output of those two seemingly unrelated commands and why doesn't this happen in the interactive console? They are not connected with a pipe. How does this work?

It seems that I still haven't quite understood basic concepts about piping in scripts.

Comment: It's not joining them so much as just displaying them together. Those two examples are pretty useless in a script unless you were assigning them to variables, in which case this would work as you would expect.

Comment: I guess it's the behavior behind "displaying them together" that I don't understand. So the first select in a script always "wins" in that it "decides" what columns there are in a table or what properties *all* the resulting objects will have?

Comment: See if this helps: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/04/30/586973.aspx  This issue isn't really the pipeline, but the default console formatting.

Comment: Done.  (Now waiting to see if it gets hammered for being a "Link-only" answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this helps: blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/04/30/586973.aspx

This issue isn't really the pipeline, but the default console formatting

Comment: I hate to have to admit this, but I don't see how that answers the question. It's two separate commands right? I could see how it would if he did `(get-process),(gci)|Select cpu,name,length` but as it is described shouldn't the DLL pass the Get-Process stream separately from the Get-ChildItem stream to determine what to display?

Comment: According to the doc, if there's no defined view for a data type, then it will set up the view using the first object that comes into the stream.  It will continue to use that view for all subsequent objects if they're of the same type.  Since you're doing a Select on both, you're creating PS custom objects. All of the objects are the same type, and it keeps using the same view.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, I just assumed that it would consider the two commands as different streams, so it would re-evaluate the properties to make available for the Format-Table formatter that parsed the objects. I suppose my issue isn't that I don't understand the process, I just don't like how they handled it. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: At the end of the article, he does admit that this should probably be considered a bug that needs to be fixed.  Since it's getting implicitly piped to Out-Default, I don't think it knows what went on on the other side of the pipeline, so it isn't really aware that it came from two different commands.